# Unresolved attribute reference 'keys' for class 'dict'

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm highlights ".keys()" on line 5 and gives me following warning for it for this illustrative code:

```
1  def testfunc():
2      mydic = {}
3      for x in range(5):
4          mydic[x] = str(x)
5      elems = set(mydic.keys())
```

Python Interpretor: python2.7 from anaconda. Pycharm v2017.3

Can someone help me understand why do I get this warning? Everything works as expected.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot duplicate: https://repl.it/@codeguru/ExperiencedLameCassowary. Granted this isn't Anaconda. I also ran the code in the python2 shell.

Comment: Totally not related, but you can just use `set(mydict)` instead of `set(mydict.keys())`. Even better, you may just be able to use `mydict.viewkeys()` which is a view of the dictionary keys that can act like a set (with constant time/space complexity for instantiation vs materializing an entirely new set object), e.g. `({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}).viewkeys() & {'a','c','d'}` -> `set(['a', 'c'])`. If you just need to use the keys of the dict for membership testing, the view object has the performance characteristics of a set.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: @user2235698 I can see this issue in PyCharm 2017.3

Comment: Yes, it is PyCharm 2017.3

Comment: @TheWanderer Please try to update to PyCharm 2017.3.3

Comment: @user2235698 You are, sir, a winner.

Comment: I'm using 2019.1 and having the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: your variable name choice is impeccable lmaoo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per user2235698's comment above and based on my verification, this is because of a buggy pycharm version. Please update your pycharm.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this bug in PyCharm 2019.3 too. The problem was that the virtualenv I used was not excluded.

More details: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34943

Comment: Option no longer available on Pro 2021